# how to loop through data from many to many relationship laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i am trying to get the name of the supplier of each product but when i do this

```
 @foreach ($products as $product )
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
      <td>{{$product->title}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->amount}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->category->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->suppliers->name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

it says Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance
however when i do this

```
<td>{{$product->suppliers}}</td>
```

this is what is what it shows me:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"test","address":"test","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"product_id":1,"supplier_id":1}}]
```

so i think the relationship exists i just cant figure out how to loop through it

side note : i did indeed insert data through phpmyadmin and not seed ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$product->suppliers` is an array of suppliers. If you want to access the names of the product's suppliers, then you will have to make another foreach loop to loop through all suppliers of a product. Because `name` is only defined in each object seperatly and not in the array.

```
 <td>
  @foreach($product->suppliers as $sup)
    {{$sup->name}} <br>
  @endforeach
</td>
```

The same should probably also work for categories.

Comment: Thank you ! idk why i didnt think of this .